# After hard shutdown, Audacity won't start

Tags: macos

Similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/916841/98479) (that one related to Ubuntu), but I'm asking about Mac.

When I try to run audacity I get the following error message:

> The system has detected that another copy of Audacity is running.
>   Running two copies of Audacity simultaneously may cause data loss or
>   cause your system to crash.Use the New or Open commands in the
>   currently running Audacity process to open multiple projects
>   simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

On Mac, this was really annoying.

Based on this [link](https://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=88589), do the following:

1. Go to `/Users/Myname/Library/Application Support/audacity` (replace `Myname` with yours of course)
2. Open file `audacity.cfg` in text editor
3. Under section `[Directories]`, find `TempDir`, which may look like this: `/Users/Myname/Library/Application Support/audacity/SessionData`
4. Go to that folder, and delete file `audacity-lock-Myname`